# ImageView aspect ratio and adjustViewBounds not working in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, imageview, android-constraintlayout

Iam working in grid layout image gallery in recycler view.
The recycler view item code is

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="9:16"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:src="@drawable/test"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I put adjustViewBounds true, false, scale type everything, but i cannot unable to remove the extra view in top and bottom. How can it be done. Red color is the extra view in the layout.

[image: The sample image from the phone]

Comment: I remove the bottom constraint also, but did not work

Comment: Your images have a different aspect ratio than the cells in your grid. You will either have extra space (like now) or you will see cropping of the images without adjusting the cell size. I am guessing that you will want to adjust the cell sizes. Try setting the height of the ImageView to `wrap_content`.

Comment: wrap_content not working

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found answer in stack overflow to create a scalable bitmap according to the view. Code posted below...

```
fun loadScaledImage(imageView: ImageView, url: String) {
            Glide
                .with(binding.context)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(url)
                .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {}
                    override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                        val width = imageView.measuredWidth
                        val bitmapWidth = resource.width
                        if (bitmapWidth > width){
                            val height = width * resource.height / bitmapWidth
                            val newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(resource, width, height, false)
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(newBitmap)
                        } else {
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(resource)
                        }
                    }
                })
        }
```